# Jquery JSON parse returns undefined

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON string but when I do I get undefined.

```
var codes = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

$.each(codes, function (key, value) {
  alert(value.Display);
});
```

Here is the contents of `codes` variable above:

```
["{ Display = string1, Sell = string2 }", 
 "{ Display = string1, Sell = string2 }"]
```

alert returns value.Display as `undefined`.  I expected "String1".  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use http://jsonlint.com to validate JSON

Comment: Your parsed `codes` value should be like this: `[{ "Display" : "string1", "Sell" : "string2" }, { "Display" : "string1", "Sell" : "string2" }]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. There is no `Display` property in the array, it's an array containing two strings.

The strings are similar to JSON, but not enough to be parsed.

If you make the strings follow the JSON standard, you can parse each item in the array into an object, then you can access the `Display` property:

```
var response = '["{ \\"Display\\": \\"string1\\", \\"Sell\\": \\"string2\\" }", "{ \\"Display\\": \\"string1\\", \\"Sell\\": \\"string2\\" }"]';

var codes = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

$.each(codes, function (key, value) {
  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(value);
  alert(obj.Display);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/wHjWf/

Alternatively, you can make the entire input follow the JSON standard, so that you can parse it into an array of objects:

```
var response = '[{ "Display": "string1", "Sell": "string2" }, { "Display": "string1", "Sell": "string2" }]';

var codes = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
console.log(codes);
$.each(codes, function (key, value) {
  alert(value.Display);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/wHjWf/1/

Comment: saved me alot today. I didn't understand why I had to do that double parse until just now. Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 6):

That's not a valid JSON string.
A correct string would look like this:

```
'{ "Display": "string1", "Sell": "string2" }'
```

Answer (score 1):

**I got this error by accidentally json-encoding my array data twice.**

Like this:

```
$twicefail = '{"penguins" : "flipper"}';
return json_encode( $twicefail );
```

Then in my view, I  picked it up like this:

```
var json_data = jQuery.parseJSON(my_json_response);

alert(json_data.penguins);      //Here json_data.penguins is undefined because I
                                //json_encoded stuff that was already json.
```

**Corrected code follows:**

```
$twicefail = '{"penguins" : "flipper"}';
return $twicefail;
```

Then in my view, pick it up like this:

```
var json_data = jQuery.parseJSON(my_json_response);

alert(json_data.penguins);     //json_data.penguins has value 'flipper'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easy try this:

```
var json = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
//get value from response of json
var Display = json[0].Display;
```

All you need is just the [0] for specify of data because this is default parameter (unset).
It works for me!